# str_detect how to distinguish between a1 and a11

Tags: r, stringr

I try to find the presence of expresions "a1" and "a11" in abc object.

```
abc <- c("a1","a1|a11","a14","a11", "a11|a14", "a1|a3|a14", "a11|a16")
```

The first query finds everything, also a11, a14 etc

```
str_detect(abc,"a1")
```

Is there a way to distinguich somehow to find only the a1 and not a11, a12 etc.

Comment: Try `"a1$"` to define ending.

Comment: `grepl("\\<a1\\>", abc)` can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundaries to enclose the pattern you want.
The last regex uses `"\<"` and `"\>"` to give an example of word boundaries that match boundaries at the beginning and at the end of the pattern, respectively. `"\\b"` matches either side of it.

```r
abc <- c("a1","a1|a11","a14","a11", "a11|a14", "a1|a3|a14", "a11|a16")

stringr::str_detect(abc,"\\ba1\\b") 
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

grepl("\\ba1\\b", abc)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
grepl("\\<a1\\>", abc)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grepl` with `fixed = FALSE` like this:

```r
abc <- c("a1","a1|a11","a14","a11", "a11|a14", "a1|a3|a14", "a11|a16")
unlist(lapply(abc, \(x) grepl(x, 'a1', fixed = FALSE)))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>